# Passing Dropdown list items into iframe through loop

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to pass dropdown list item to iframe source(src) through loop, its working, but loop is working so fast that its directly goes to last index of dropdown list and iframe loading only the last index item of dropdown. I have tried both setTimeout and setInterval but it is not working.

```
Here is my code...
//Dropdown list
<label>Faculty (Employee Code)</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="faculties" id="faculties" onchange="update_chart(this.value,document.getElementById('myIframe'))">
            <option>--Select--</option>
        </select>

//frame
<iframe id="myIframe" src="chart_course_wise.php" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

<script>

function update_chart(str, myIframe) {
        var dept = document.getElementById('dept_code').value;
        var sem = document.getElementById('sem').value;
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var emp_code = regExp.exec(str);
        myIframe.src = "chart_course_wise.php?fac=" + emp_code[1] + "&dept=" + dept + "&sem=" + sem;
    }


    function generate(){
        var element = document.getElementById('faculties'),i;
        var length = element.options.length;

        for(i=1;i<length;i++){
           var ddl = element.options[i].value;
           update_chart(ddl,document.getElementById('myIframe'));
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I think speed of for has nothing to do here, you should pass all parameter at once because every time you are overwriting  the parameters so, at the end you have the last parameters sent.

Comment: But i want to send parameter one by one otherwise my further code will not work

Comment: Are you storing each parameter sent in chart_course_wise.php in a database, $_SESSION or something? Because otherwise you will always have the last parameters. Each call to chart_course_wise.php is another thread opened

Comment: I'm passing each dropdown menu item as parameter through URL of iframe. But whenever loop runs it always goes to last index of dropdown menu item.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, your `generate` function is called from somewhere not in the snippet.

If you turn you `generate()` into a JavaScript [generator `function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), and add that to you the onload event of the frame, you might get what you want:

```
function update_chart(str, myIframe) {
    var dept = document.getElementById('dept_code').value;
    var sem = document.getElementById('sem').value;
    var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var emp_code = regExp.exec(str);
    myIframe.src = "chart_course_wise.php?fac=" + emp_code[1] + "&dept=" + dept + "&sem=" + sem;
    myIframe.document.body.onload = gen.next
}

function* generator() {
    var element = document.getElementById('faculties'),
        i;
    var length = element.options.length;

    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        var ddl = element.options[i].value;
        yield update_chart(ddl, document.getElementById('myIframe'));
    }
}

var gen = generator();
gen.next(); // this is how you execute the generator
```

Now you can start the generator, why will run until the first `yield` statement.
It will then exit, until `myIframe onload` event is triggered, which will execute `gen.next()`, in turn causing the generator to resume execution, rinse repeat.

Comment: yes that generate function is calling from a button onclick().

Comment: now it is showing "let is not supported by current javascript version"

Comment: @DhirajKumar replace `let` with `var` :)

Comment: @DhirajKumar please check the Browser compatibility for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*#Browser_compatibility

Comment: i have changed by javascript version now its accepting 'let' but still code is not working as i want

Comment: Where does it go wrong @DhirajKumar? I need more information to help you :)

Comment: Actually i want to pass each item of dropdown menu to iframe src through loop and print it or save it , but whenever the loop run it goes to last index of dropdown menu

Comment: @DhirajKumar how many items are in the dropdown? is there a reason for the loop to start at 1, not 0? Otherwise it works as designed, it iterates over all the items and switches the iframe after it loaded immediately.